# Android MotionEvent and View coordinates

Tags: android, view

Could I get View position but with coordinates in the same coordinate system as MotionEvent.getRawX()/MotionEvent.getRawY()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`View.getLocationOnScreen()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5b%5d%29) should do the trick.

Comment: After orientation change it shows diffrent position than MotionEvent.